# How is content published from Author to publish Environment in CQ5?

Tags: aem, crx

I have installed two instances of CQ5-quickstart.jar . One as [Author](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/installing_cq.html#Installing%20an%20Author%20Instance) and one as [Publish](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/installing_cq.html#Installing%20a%20Publish%20Instance).

I have a very basic query. If I publish/edit some content in the Author Environment, HOW will it be visible in my Publish environment ?

I mean, is the flow of code/data between these two instances mentioned somewhere that I've missed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to 'Activate' the page first. Only then it will be available on the Publish environment. Read this page please .

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/wcm/page_publish.html

Answer (score 2):

Hi you could also check on configuring replication agents
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_cq.html#Replicating from Author to Publish

Answer (score 2):

First check the publish environment in Replication properly and test connection is established or not.If it is success than activate content.While activating un check those two options and click activate than the changes are can see in publish.

If any modified jsp code need to build in package and push to live.

Thanks 
Ramesh v